# Tomcat 7 - Connection reset

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

Hey I'm using Tomcat 7 and HttpClient 4.3.3. I am trying to connect to my Servlet with multiple threads but I often receive `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`. When I suspend the Servlet's threads at the first line I'm still receiving the exception on my client.
My question: is the cause of this problem maybe be linked with a too small number of maximum active connections? If not could please anyone help me with the problem?

```java
try{

        // create new httpPost request with url of his class
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( "http://192.168.1.229:8080/test/test" );

        // create params and add it to httpPost
        List<NameValuePair> paramList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramList.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "json_req", format ) );
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity( paramList );
        httpPost.setEntity( formEntity );

        // execute request and save response
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpPost, context );

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        resp = content.available() > 0;

        content.close();
        response.close();
        // return the response
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke(CPoolProxy.java:138)
    at $Proxy0.receiveResponseHeader(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at com.pribas.flightcacheservlet.servlet.HTTPThread.run(HTTPThread.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Code which starts the threads:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{
    FileUtil.init();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal( 1000 );
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute( 1000 );
    cm.setDefaultSocketConfig( SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive( true ).setSoReuseAddress( true ).setSoTimeout( 3000 ).build() );
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager( cm ).build();

    HTTPThread.THREAD_COUNT = 300;
    HTTPThread.start = new CountDownLatch( HTTPThread.THREAD_COUNT );

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[ HTTPThread.THREAD_COUNT ];

    for( int i = 0; i < HTTPThread.THREAD_COUNT; i++ ){
        threads[ i ] = new Thread( new HTTPThread( httpClient ) );
    }

    for( Thread thread : threads ){
        thread.start();
    }

    for( Thread thread : threads ){
        thread.join();
    }

    httpClient.close();

    System.out.println( "Average response time: " + calAverage( HTTPThread.times ) + " milliseconds." );
}
```

Comment: Please provide the client code you are trying to make connection with.

Comment: added client code & exception

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the JavaDoc says about the mentioned exception:

> Thrown to indicate that there is an error in the underlying protocol such as a TCP error

Through my personal experience, I faced such cases  seems that it is not the other connection end (server) who closed the connection but your client. Otherwise you would receive another message: `Connection reset by peer`

This can happen due to many causes and in your case I guess it is related to the fact that you have not colsed the `HttpClient` instance at the end of your work unit; so try adding below line in the finally block of your `try` statement:

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch( Exception e )
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally 
{
  httpClient.close(); //close the underlying client.
}
```

### Update:

You may also need to enable the `SO_KEEPALIVE` to keep sockets alive:

```
    cm.setDefaultSocketConfig( 
        SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true)
          .setSoReuseAddress(true)
          .setSoTimeout(3000)
          .build());
```

Comment: the httpclient is used for multiple connections. it gets closed at some other place after all threads are finished.

Comment: You may update your issue with all relevant code base.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. In my opinion all relevant code is now present. Do you need the server code?

Comment: Non need for apologies, you are welcome. You can take a look at my update.

Comment: Sadly nothing changed. Still receiving exceptions.

Comment: I tested the code on some other machine and on localhost and the exception was not there anymore. So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the underlying network. Nevertheless thanks for your help.

Comment: I should have mentioned such a thing but got stack with the code source instead of crossing all the edge. You can use WireSharck to track all packet traffic around your application. Check also all firewall and network related stuff :)